# SQL Update with Subquery in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a bit of experience in SQL and came across the following code for SQLPlus/Oracle. I'm a bit confused why you do an update with this code. 
The table example is table1 with columns col1, col2, col3

```
update e
    set grade='HD'
    where stu_no=(
          select stu_no
          from e
          where  result >80 and grade !='HD')
      and unit_code=(
          select unit_code
          from e
          where result >80 and and grade !='HD' ) ;
```

Why can't it simply be an update like the following,

```
update e
   set grade = 'HD'
 where result >= 80 
   and grade != 'HD'
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Added the actual code without changing the table names

Comment: Note: the subqueries **should** be scalar subqueries, or the `= (subquery)` should actually be `IN (subquery)`

Comment: This is definitely different from what you posted initially - now there are four columns in play, in your re-writing there were only three.

Comment: Sorry. Does this make it clearer why this method is suggested as opposed to just looking at the result and grade columns?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the condition subqueries (`select stu_no from e where result > 80 and grade !='HD'`) **must** return only one result, or otherwise the query will return an error, then it really can be done without subqueries.

Maybe that's intended: only update when there is a single record that matches the conditions. But that's quite an overhead for such a simple check.

Please observe the context in which this was made. Some things in Computer Science can be quite tricky.

Comment: I changed the queries above with the actual table names of the context. May be that helps. Why would the above code update only a single record? Won't the subqueries return multiple rows if the conditions of the where clause are met?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update IFF another record `exists`, with the same {col1,col2} and with (col2 > 0 AND col3 <> 'XYZ'):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  SET col3 = 'XYZ'
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    from table1 ex
    WHERE ex.col1 = t1.col1 AND ex.col2 = t1.col2
    AND col2 > 0 and col3 <> 'XYZ'
    )
    ;
```